# angular architecture for no page found display full page

Tags: angular

1. What's the best policy to architecture my angular project for angular routing, any good sources or books?
2. How to show "no page found" without displaying any other components, my angular architecture is as follows

index.html

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="main-container">
    <header>
        <app-menu></app-menu> //for dark/light theme, language
        <app-header></app-header> //title
        <br>
        <app-nav></app-nav> //navbar menu
        <br>
    </header>
    <section>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> //page body, to load further components
    </section>
    <footer>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

"nopagefound" routing path

```
{ path: '**', component: NopagefoundComponent },
```

it activates for any site like "mydomain/xyz" that is not on routing path 
but it displays like follow, with other components

```
<app-menu>
<app-header>
<app-nav>
{{no page found}}
<app-footer>
```

my goal is to display it like

```
{{ no page found }}
```

without any other components

UPDATE:
Thank you, i got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seperate your routes:

First, create a layout component:

Then set your routes like below:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
       // other route
      }
  },
  { path: 'not_found', component: NopagefoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not_found' },
]
```

Next, move the content of your `app.component.html` who need only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to layout component,

Done !

Answer (score 0):

1. First method:
   use a service guard and include inside of your routing module .
2. Second method: you can use 2 routing modules on lazy .
3. Third method: you can inject routes inside the components (app.nav, footer, ...) and discuss whether the route is a not found or another one.